# How to run a calculation until true within a loop python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, do-while

Hi so a quick question for spyder python 3.6

Say I have a simple while loop or if statement.

```
import random

from decimal import Decimal

usraccbal = (1000.01)

def rate():
    ratecontents = (random.random() * (1.202 - 0.308) + 0.308)
    return ratecontents

def newconvert(amount, rate):
    a = (amount * rate)
    return a, amount

b = rate()
rate1 = b

c = newconvert(usraccbal, rate1)

newcnvrt = (c[0])

prevusraccbal = (c[1])

#while or if here
if newcnvrt == prevusraccbal or newcnvrt < prevusraccbal:
    #Continue calculating until newcnvrt > prevusraccbal 
    #then update values
else:
    #Update values 
    usraccbal = newcnvrt
```

As you can see I would like to continue trying to get a newcnvrt which equals more than prevusraccbal either in an if or a while loop. So importantly it is constantly getting a new exchange rate and trying to use that.

The code is actually in a function normally which has root.after(3000,results) and is actioned by a button press

Comment: Is the update done once or inside each iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to replace `.... < .... or .... == ....` with `.... <= ....`.

Just add a `while` with your condition. It executes until the condition is no longer `True`, and then the loop exits.

```
while newcnvrt <= prevusraccbal:
    ... # calculate until condition is false

usraccbal = newcnvrt
```

Comment: Thank you even once explained i still had a hard time deciphering the logic once running

Comment: DID WORK hey would you mind helping me implement that in the code im working on i cant figure out how to do it I think i need to add another while loop somewhere so an amount does not change during the .after loop can i email you a txt of it for an ide?

Comment: @GoulouhAnwar The easiest and fastest way to get help is by asking a question here :)